# Python change Tqdm bar style

Tags: python, tqdm

Is it possible to change the tqdm bar from

```
[Step 1]: 100%|███████████████████████████  | 109/109 [00:03<00:00, 32.46it/s]
```

to something like

```
[Step 1]: 100%[==========================>  ] 109/109 [00:03<00:00, 32.46it/s]
```

Answer (score 15):

```
for i in range tqdm(<iterator>, total=<>, ascii=' >='):
    <your code here>
```

This should do the trick, the **ascii** argument, reads the first character is the fill character, that is space here, you can use some other character like ascii="░▒█" and the bar would look like

```
0%[░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░]
```

The last character is the character which it fills when the progress bar has progressed a certain amount like

```
30%[███████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░]
```

While any character you put in between will be to fill while it is progressing, like say while it moves from 30% to 40%.

```
35%[███████▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░]
```

I hope that explains your question, you can have multiple progressing characters in the middle, like

```
ascii=" ▖▘▝▗▚▞█"
```

Try this one out, it is real fun to watch this progress, provided your console supports all the Unicode characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `ascii` argument when instantiate the bar. The first char is the empty one and the second is fill char.

```
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep
with tqdm(total=100, ascii=' =') as pbar:
    for i in range(10):
        sleep(0.1)
        pbar.update(10)
```